# Showing countable collection $\{ (a, b): a< b\text{ and } a, b \in \Bbb Q \}$ generates standard topology.

Tags: general-topology

From definition of standard topology, the only things I find different is that in standard there are no restriction on $a, b$ to be rational and no restriction for collection to be countable. How do I proceed? Shall I show that topology genrated by either of them if finer than each other?

Comment: Do you already know that $\{(a.b)| a<b \land a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ generates the standard topology?

Comment: @5xum I do but no such restriction for $a, b \in \Bbb Q$ as in my question

Comment: Hint: for real $a<b$, write $(a,b)$ as the (countable) union of $(a_n, b_n)$ where $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: An observation: "countable" here is not a restriction, but a remark.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I guess so since rational numbers are countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* The set $A = \{(a,b) :  a<b \text{  with }a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ generates the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Define your collection as $B= \{(a,b) :  a<b \text{  with }a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, then clearly $B \subset A$. If you can show that all sets in $A$ can be generated by sets in $B$, then you are done. Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: I suppose this is equivalent to show that $\mathcal T_\Bbb R$ is finer than $\mathcal T_\Bbb Q$ and $\mathcal T_\Bbb Q$ is finer than $\mathcal T_\Bbb R$ simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, except it is sufficient to work with these basis elements instead of with arbitrary sets in the topology. This makes the working easier.